# Highlighting a word using JavaScript, HTML, and CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I've been trying to make a typing test website and am almost done with it. One of the last things that I need to do is highlight the word where the user is typing. e.g : if the quote is "hello world" and the user is on hello; hello should be highlighted. I couldn't really find anything for this online. The code is below:

```js
var input = document.getElementById("boch");
input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 32) {
    event.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById("bocho").click();
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
}

input[type=text] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1%;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

h1 {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
}

div {
  height: 10em;
  position: relative
}

html {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}

body {
  background: linear-gradient(-20deg, #e73c7e, #23a6d5, #23d5ab);
  background-size: 1000000% 1000000%;
}

button {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  width: 100px
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>repl.it</title>
</head>
<h1>
  bocho is cool
</h1>

</div>
<div id="typing-area">
  <input type="text" id="boch">
  <button id="bocho" onclick="document.getElementById('boch').value = ''">Enter</button>

</html>
```

I will be using only one quote which is "Bocho is cool" so that should be highlighted.

Comment: i dun really got what you need, do you mean to highlight the word within the paragraph if it's written (CASE SENSITIVE) into the textbox ?

Comment: Yes. that is what i mean

Comment: Is the word highlighted until they have typed it correctly and pressed space? What happens if they mistype?

Comment: If they mistype the highlight should turn red.

Comment: The way I would approach this is to have the typing  sentences in an array by character then use the onkeypress event to trigger a check function  `<input type="text" onkeypress="checkFunction()">`. This function will fire after every keypress and will check if they user keypressed equals the index of the character array if does you can change css style with js.  Example: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/design-a-typing-speed-test-game-using-javascript/

Comment: ok ill try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a new version with a sandbox for you to play with.
This version should work perfectly fine

You can click 'run code snippet' below to test it out

```js
var element = document.querySelector("#boch");

element.onkeyup = function() {
  var value = element.value;

 if(value.includes("bocho")) {
    document.getElementById('word-1').style.backgroundColor = 'green';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('word-1').style.backgroundColor = 'white';
  }

  if(value.includes("bocho is")) {
    document.getElementById('word-2').style.backgroundColor = 'green';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('word-2').style.backgroundColor = 'white';
  }

  if(value.includes("bocho is cool")) {
    document.getElementById('word-3').style.backgroundColor = 'green';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('word-3').style.backgroundColor = 'white';
  }
  
}
```

```html
<h1>
   <span id="word-1">bocho</span> <span id="word-2">is</span> <span id="word-3">cool</span>
</h1>

<input type="text" id="boch">
```